# TextField individual character's background colors

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I am trying to set the background color for each individual character in a TextField. Setting the individual foreground colors is trivial but I am not seeing it for the background colors.

Any insight? Or do I need to roll my own.

thanks in advance.

edit: forgot to add. I am parsing a telnet stream so pushing it to htmlText would just slow things down. So that isn't an option. The output speed on the client side is time critical.

Comment: Is using Flex 4 / TLF an option?

Comment: It very well may be. thanks. Seems to support some "highlight" color in cs5 so I assume I can do it programmatically. Looking it up now.

Comment: Looks like that will work for what I need. Pop that into an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using the `TLF framework`, specifically by setting the `foregroundColor` on the appropriate `FlowElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import CSS into Flash as well as text and apply the styles.
I have not used it to style background but I think it is worth the shot.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
var cssLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var css:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();

function cssLoaded(e:Event):void{
    css.parseCSS(e.target.data);
    tf.styleSheet = css;

    for(var i:int = 0; i < wordList.length; i++){
        tf.htmlText += "<h4>" + wordList[i] + "</h4>";
    }
```

<sub>Source : [AS3: Load external .txt and .css](http://snipplr.com/view/4452/as3-load-external-txt-and-css/)</sub>

Comment: An interesting thought, but unless I am mistaken using css forces you to use htmlText which isn't an option for me. Also CSS in as3 doesn't support background colors on text just the foreground colors. Unless this has changed recently.Basically what would happen is I would be parsing 4 bytes out from the stream and turning into a whole html tag <text color="#ffffff"> so from 1 char to more than a dozen This would create a heavy load and slow everything down. Those ESC sequences are constant and there are almost as many as there are text.